# How to assign api response to variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am sending API request to google server using `DirectionsService` class. and getting response also.But I am not able to assign that response to variable.

I tried in the following way it's not working(getting undefined).

```
var gettingApiresponce=function(sourcePlace,destinationPlace){
var directionService=new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var responce;
directionService.route(
    {
        origin:sourcePlace,
        destination:destinationPlace,
        travelMode:"DRIVING"
    },function(res,status){
        responce=res;
    });
return responce;
 };
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The directions service is asynchronous.  Anything that uses the response should run in (or after) the call back function.  For that reason, you can't "return" the result.

```
// put in the global scope.
var responce;
var gettingApiresponce=function(sourcePlace,destinationPlace){
var directionService=new google.maps.DirectionsService();

directionService.route(
    {
        origin:sourcePlace,
        destination:destinationPlace,
        travelMode:"DRIVING"
    },function(res,status){
        //this will set the global variable responce, but anything that needs to be 
        // done with the returned value should be done here.
        responce=res;
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(res);
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        // etc.            
    });
    // can't do this returns before the callback function runs.
    //return responce;
 };
```